# calculating number off panels and posts needed for given fence length

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a function called `fence` that takes two scalar inputs:

- `lng`, the length of a straight fence we need to build
- `seg`, the length of one segment of fencing material.

A segment needs to have a pole at both ends, but two neighboring segments always share a pole. The function returns two scalar outputs: the number of segments we need for the given length of fence and the number of poles needed. Note that a segment can be cut shorter if needed.

For example, to build a 75m long straight fence using 10m segments, we need 8 segments.

My code:

```
function [a,b]=fence(lng,seg) 
    poleLength=1;
    a=lng;
    tot=seg+poleLenth;
    b= ceil(lng/tot);
end
```

This is currently giving the wrong solution for the inputs `fence(100, 10)`

I appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Right direction would be to calculate amount of segments needed with help of ceil function

```
a = ceil( lng / seg );
```

and calculate amount of poles needed, which is

`b = a + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You should read the question once again and try to understand what are they asking for.
Use this code:

```
function [tt,mm] = fence(lng,seg)
   d = (lng./seg);
   tt = ceil(d);
   mm = (tt + 1);
end
```